# How to build responsive web using templates and bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, meteor

I'm building a web app with meteor. Right now, I'm trying to create this web page containing two templates.

Basic design layouts:
[image]

First template: This template includes the Left Menu Bar (4 tabs).

Next is what it looks like after adding the 2nd template (purple).

[image]

What I want to do is to switch templates in the purple area for the 4 tabs, while keeping the rest layout. I'm using bootstrap to set the layout. However, when I try to resize the window to a smaller one:

issue 1. the green and purple parts will stack on each other.

issue 2. After I set a top padding to move the purple area down, when I scroll down, there is still a part where these two templates will stack on each other.

What would be the best approach here?

Here are my codes:

```
<template name="layout">
{{header}}

{{> Template.dynamic template=template1}}
{{> Template.dynamic template=purpleTemplate2}}

{{> footer}}    
</template>
```

Inside first template:

```
<div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3"  >
       //content - four tabs
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
   </div>
</div>
```

Inside second template:

```
 <div id="tab1">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3"  >          
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
       //tab 1 content
   </div>
 </div>
```

same as ...tab2 ...tab3 ...tab4

I hope this makes sense. I'll be glad to provide you with more details if needed. Thank you in advance for your help!!

**JUST ADDED:**

Ideally, it should look like this when I resize the browser:

[image]

However, it looks like this:

[image]

The left menu bar stays on top, which is what I want. But when I scroll down the purple area will scroll up and cover the menu. Also, the footer seems to stay with the purple area as well.

Answer (score 0):

We can start by setting up wrappers to the dynamic templates. like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3"  >
  {{> Template.dynamic template=template1}}
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
  {{> Template.dynamic template=purpleTemplate2}}
</div>
```

This means you probably not need the bootstrap cols inside your dynamic html.

heres an example I whipped up:
http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/PGwAXL

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried but it didn't work. I've just added two pictures to show what the problem is.

Comment: @WoShiNiBaBa I understand the problem better now, I changed my answer to try to resolve your problem. if you are still having issue we may need to look at some of your styling.